# how to pass data from controller to view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

1. I am having problem to send data from controller to view.
2. When I am passing value from controller to view it become null.
3. I want to display Appointment details of
               particular doctor.

For example, if Patient XYZ want to appointment form ABC Doctor on
                Particular time and date then that selected doctor only can view
                details of appointment..and patient also can see his appointment
                details.

**I have Appointment Model**

```
 public partial class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeOfDrAvailablity { get; set; }

    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

**Doctor Controller** (I'm trying so far...in this I get the dr.ID and Patient.Id but when it pass to view it become null)

```
  public ActionResult Appointment(Doctor doc)
    {

        var app=new Appointment();

        app.DoctorId = db.Doctors.FirstOrDefault().Id;
        app.PatientId = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault().Id;

        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal role='form' " }))
   {
    <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor((model=>model.Appointments.FirstOrDefault().Date), new { @class = "Form-control" })
</td>                  
 <td>
 @Html.DisplayFor((model => model.Id), new { @class = " Form-control" })
  </td>                    
  <td>                        
 @Html.DisplayFor((model => model.Appointments.FirstOrDefault().PatientId), new { @class = " Form-control" })
 </td>                   
 <td> 
  <div class="btn-group">
   <div class="btn btn-Sucess">
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id =Model.Id })
  </div>
```

Comment: Your not passing your model to the view - it need to be `return View(app);` And `DisplayFor()` does not generate controls so why do you have a form? But that does not even seem to match what your doing anyway - what is `model => model.Appointments.FirstOrDefault().PatientId`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke actully i am adding `@model Hms.Models.Doctor` so i am adding **Appointment**  model in  **Doctor View**

Comment: By adding `@model Hms.Models.Doctor` you are just saying the that this page uses that model. But you are returning View() without sending an instance of that model to the view. So you should do what @Stephen-Mueche suggested and just add: `return View(app);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass your model to your view as follows

```
public ActionResult Appointment(Doctor doc)
{
    var app = new Appointment();

    [...]

    return View(app);
}
```

Your view then references your model as follows

```
@model MyProject.Appointment

<p>Doctor: @Model.DoctorId</p>
<p>Patient: @Model.PatientId</p>
```